# XAF Mobile DetailView loads slow after first time

Tags: c#, mobile, xaf

I am working on a XAF mobile application.
I have a Business Object class, which has more than 100 fields.
In the Detail View, i am hiding some fields, nearly 50 fields.
I have no issue in hiding fields, it works perfectly.
I am having issue with loading speed of detail view.
For the first time, the detail view loads quickly.
but, next time it takes more time to load.
[Remove Cache if the Detail View loads slow](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T818278/detail-view-mobile-application-loading-very-slow-when-i-use-appearance-criteria-for-my)
With above link as reference,
I have also tried to speed up loading of detail view by removing cache, but, still it takes more time to load like nearly 50 seconds. Can anyone help me to load the detail view faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the reference of the solution provided by Devexpress support team in [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T848122/mobile-applications-opens-a-detail-view-very-slowly-if-a-controller-registers-a-custom) ticket